# Read CSV in R with first column as dataframe header

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a simply text file where the first column is names (strings) and the second column is values (floats). As an example, names and ages:

```
Name, Age
John, 32
Heather, 46,
Jake, 23
Sally, 19
```

I'd like to read this in as a dataframe (call this `df`) but transposed so that I can access ages by names such that `df$John` would return `32`. How can I do this?

Previous I tried creating a new dataframe, `tdf`, looping through the data in a `for` loop, assigning each `name` and `age` and then inserting into the empty dataframe as `tdf[name] = age` but this did not work as I expected.

Comment: Not sure with `read.csv()` or `readr::read_csv()` but why not just read in like you have done, then use `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::select()` to get the values you need in your analysis pipeline?

Comment: Why not transpose after reading it?

Comment: Just `split` the the Age by Name to get a key/value pair and then you can access the value by `lst[["john"]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can read your data using `read.table()`.

Then you can transpose it using `t()` and set colnames after.

Example:

If df is:

```
df=read.table("dummydata", header=T, sep=",")

df
     Name Age
1    John  32
2 Heather  46
3    Jake  23
4   Sally  19
```

You transpose the age and then transform them into a dataframe:

```
tdf=as.data.frame(t(df$Age))
colnames(tdf)=t(df$Name)
```

So tdf will return:

```
tdf
  John Heather Jake Sally
1   32      46   23    19
```

And, as you asked, tdf$John will return:

```
tdf$John
[1] 32
```

---

Now, if you have more than two columns you can do the same but instead of indicating the name of the column you can simply indicate the position using brackets.

```
df=read.table("dummydata", header=T, sep=",")
```

With t(df[2:ncol(df)]) you transpose the whole table starting from the second column, no matter the number of columns. The first column will be the names after the transpose.

```
tdf=as.data.frame(t(df[2:ncol(df)]))
```

Then you set the columnames.

```
colnames(tdf)=t(df[1])

tdf$John
[1] 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the data into a data frame, `DF` (see Note).

**1)** Assign the names to the rows of `DF` in which case this will give John's age without having to create a new data structure:

```
rownames(DF) <- DF$Name
DF["John", "Age"]
## [1] 32
```

**2)** Alternatively, split `DF` into a named list in which case you can get the precise syntax requested:

```
ages <- with(DF, split(Age, Name))
ages$John
## [1] 32
```

**3)** This alternative would also create the same list:

```
ages <- with(DF, setNames(as.list(Age), Name))
```

**Note:** `DF` in reproducible form is as follows.  (We have removed the trailing comma on one line in the question but if it is really there add fill = TRUE to the `read.csv` line.)

```
Lines <- "Name, Age
John, 32
Heather, 46
Jake, 23
Sally, 19"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should add the the row as header when you read from the file

```
read.csv2(filename, as.is = TRUE, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but hopefully helpful. The "row.names" parameter allows you to select the desired column as header:

```
read.csv("df.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```